# Does anyone has a camera stabilization of open source code

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I use the camera of robot to detect the road, I found the result is bad because when the robot moves,the camera is unstable. so I need found an open source code to stable the image. But I search many open code webs and can't find something useful.so I ask help here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201124/does-anyone-has-a-camera-stabilization-of-open-source-code/) by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I've never used it, but [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) likely has a good implementation. I would start [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/videostab/doc/videostab.html).

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2015-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on 2015-01-16**:
thank you,does the implementation have in opencv2.0?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-17**:
@cros: do not use answers to post comments: use comments for that. I've reposted your answer as a comment under @Airuno2L's answer.